# Python unittest failfast=True not taking effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I created some tests with Python 3.8 and unittest framework and want to stop running next tests if one of them fails by adding the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(failfast=True)
```

However this seem to have no effect at all and even if the first test fails the next tests continiue. Here is an example of my code:

```
import unittest


class RegressionTestsForEarlyRealSoccerEvents(unittest.TestCase):
    failed_tests = False

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        pass

    def setUp(self):
        print(f'\n---------- {self._testMethodName}')

    def test_01_verify_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2, 'fail')

    def test_02_verify_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1, 'fail')
        print(self.failed_tests)

    def test_03_verify_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1, 'fail')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(failfast=True)
```

Anything I am missing?

Comment: How do you run the test? CLI or with an IDE?

Comment: I run it with an IDE

Comment: What IDE? and how exactly?
Try opening a console at the working directory of the test and run `python -m <name of your file>`